# Is it possible to construct a url to adwords web application?

Tags: api, google-ads-api

Is it possible to construct a url to adwords web application?

If I know the account and campaign that I want to visit on AdWords, is it possible to construct the url for it?

It seems to have this pattern:

https://adwords.google.com/billing/ui/app?id=*number_for_id*&v=*number_for_v*&__u=*number_for_u&__c=number_for_c*#PAYMENT_OPTIONS

what's id, __u and __c?

Any help will appreciate.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this isn't possible. The pattern you noticed is probably correct, but __c and __u are undocumented parameters that the site uses IMO and Google hasn't documented on what these parameters are or how to generate them.

Cheers,
Anash